# No puedo ejecutar ninguna aplicación slim

Tags: php, windows, xampp, slim

Estoy haciendo una api en slim y el desde ayer me empezó aparecer estos errores y ya no se qe hacer para solucionarlo
Ya cambié los permisos en todo mi xamp y nada, creo un proyecto nuevo y ni siquiera puedo abrirlo.
El error en cuestión :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Failed opening required 'app' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

```
    <?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Handlers\HttpErrorHandler;
use App\Application\Handlers\ShutdownHandler;
use App\Application\ResponseEmitter\ResponseEmitter;
use App\Application\Settings\SettingsInterface;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Factory\ServerRequestCreatorFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate PHP-DI ContainerBuilder
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

if (false) { // Should be set to true in production
    $containerBuilder->enableCompilation(__DIR__ . '/../var/cache');
}

// Set up settings
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../app/settings.php';
$settings($containerBuilder);

// Set up dependencies
$dependencies = require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
$dependencies($containerBuilder);

// Set up repositories
$repositories = require __DIR__ . '/../app/repositories.php';
$repositories($containerBuilder);

// Build PHP-DI Container instance
$container = $containerBuilder->build();

// Instantiate the app
AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();
$callableResolver = $app->getCallableResolver();

// Register middleware
$middleware = require __DIR__ . '/../app/middleware.php';
$middleware($app);

// Register routes
$routes = require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
$routes($app);

/** @var SettingsInterface $settings */
$settings = $container->get(SettingsInterface::class);

$displayErrorDetails = $settings->get('displayErrorDetails');
$logError = $settings->get('logError');
$logErrorDetails = $settings->get('logErrorDetails');

// Create Request object from globals
$serverRequestCreator = ServerRequestCreatorFactory::create();
$request = $serverRequestCreator->createServerRequestFromGlobals();

// Create Error Handler
$responseFactory = $app->getResponseFactory();
$errorHandler = new HttpErrorHandler($callableResolver, $responseFactory);

// Create Shutdown Handler
$shutdownHandler = new ShutdownHandler($request, $errorHandler, $displayErrorDetails);
register_shutdown_function($shutdownHandler);

// Add Routing Middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Add Body Parsing Middleware
$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();

// Add Error Middleware
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware($displayErrorDetails, $logError, $logErrorDetails);
$errorMiddleware->setDefaultErrorHandler($errorHandler);

// Run App & Emit Response
$response = $app->handle($request);
$responseEmitter = new ResponseEmitter();
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

Subido un index de ejemplo de un proyecto nuevo que me sale el mismo error solo que en cambio "public"

Comment: segun parece estas intentando acceder a "app" pero no existe... puedes mostrar el contenido de tu archivo index.php?

Comment: igual acabo de creear un proyecto en blanco y me sale el mismo error
Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Failed opening required 'public' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
solo con la carpera public, literal para todos los proyectos slim me fallan con ese error

Comment: sin el contenido de index ... esta dificil adivinar el codigo rekacionado al error

Comment: ahí subí el index, donde me sale en vvez de errror en app en public, pq es un proyecto nuevo sin ningun cambio

Comment: y actualizaste tu autoload???

Comment: pareciera que esto esta mal: require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: ya que el autoload no encuentra el nodo app

Comment: voy a probar haciendo eso, ya ayer tiré la toalla jejej

Comment: nada, incluso creo un proyecto con laravel y me funciona de 10

Comment: bueno pareciera que lo que tienes declarado en el composer/autoload no hace match con tu estructura de directorios.... tendrias que subirnos esa informacion para evaluar el contexto ....

Comment: aveces lo he soucionado con un: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: ya lo pruebo, ese me faltaba

Comment: que te salio???

Comment: nada, siguen el mismo error, no se que onda con esto, creo q lo haré con laravel

Comment: ya te dije por donde va el asunto ... es problema con los namespaces

Comment: y el autoloader

Comment: esta buscando una carpeta que no existe y te escupe el error stream

Comment: pero la carpeta está 
estoy creando proyecto desde 0 que antes funcionaba y ya no funciona y me pasó un proyecto un amigo que corría en su máquina y en la mía no funciona

Comment: que corra en su maquina no quiere decir que va a correr en la tuya ... son estructuras (PC) diferentes